# Java Selenium custom method to get name of webelement as parameters

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using Java Selenium and Page Object in my project, want to create a custom method which will get two strings as parameters, combine them and call right webelement to perform some actions.

Below example of my Page Object

```
public class Test extends Base {

public Test() {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}


@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@id='question1No']")
WebElement question1Yes;

@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@id='question1No']")
WebElement question1No;


public Object GetField(String answer, String question) {
    Field field = null;
    try {
        field = Test.class.getField((question+answer).replace("\"", ""));
        return field.get(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public void answerQuestion(String answer, String question) {    
    WebElement element = (WebElement)GetField(answer,question);
    element.click();
```

}

And call that method for example:

```
answerQuestion("Yes", "question1")
```

calling this method should perform click on question1Yes element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added to above answer updating it based on OP need along with package name

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class Test extends base{

    @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@id='question1No']")
    public WebElement question1Yes;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@id='question1No']")
    public WebElement question1No;

    public Test() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void answerQuestion(String answer, String question) {
        WebElement temp = null;
        try {               
            Field field = Test.class.getField(question + answer);
            temp = (WebElement) field.get(this);
            temp.click();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle the exception here when there is wrong field
            // throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can use common method for getting the fields

```
public Object GetField(String answer, String question) {
        Field field = null;
        try {
            field = Test.class.getField(question + answer);
            return field.get(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

So that your code will be like

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class Test extends base {

    @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@id='question1No']")
    public WebElement question1Yes;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@id='question1No']")
    public WebElement question1No;

    public Test() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void answerQuestion(String answer, String question) {    
         WebElement temp = (WebElement)GetField(answer,question);
         temp.click();  
    }

    public Object GetField(String answer, String question) {
        Field field = null;
        try {
            field = Test.class.getField(question + answer);
            return field.get(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: getting error: `java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: question1Yes` even this element exist

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: @IhorHarmatii Change `WebElement question1Yes` to public like `public WebElement question1Yes`

Comment: @IhorHarmatii Also interchange the argument position in `(WebElement)GetField(answer,question)` which should be like `(WebElement)GetField(question,answer)` in the method `answerQuestion`

Comment: tried that, but still `java.lang.NoSuchFieldException`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219825/discussion-between-ihor-harmatii-and-mohamed-sulaimaan-sheriff).

Answer (score 2):

You may use reflection.

```
Field field = Test.class.getField("question1Yes");
WebElement element = (WebElement) field.get(this);
```

And then you can do whatever you want with your WebElement

upd.
if field is private, write `field.setAccessible(true);`

Comment: Also make `WebElement ` fields as public

Comment: Did you mean something like this? `public void answerQuestion(String answer, String question) {
  Field field = Test.class.getField(question+answer);
  WebElement element = (WebElement) field.get(this);
  element.click();
 }`

Comment: @IhorHarmatii, yes. Also, you can make method to get WebElement by its name (if you need)

Comment: @AndrewBlagij I am quite sure if I understand correct, can you please provide example of how "make method to get WebElement by its name"

Comment: @AndrewBlagij and also from what packages I need to import Field and Test?

Comment: @IhorHarmatii Test it is your class from which you want to get your field.
Field import from java.lang.reflect.Field

Comment: @IhorHarmatii
(this method will throw some exceptions)
`public WebElement getWebElemen (String name)  {
Field field = this.getClass.getField(name);
field.setAccessible(true);
return (WebElement) field.get(this);
}`


And then use getWebElement with parameter - string which is name of field you want. This method you should write in that class, where this field is located